# How to serve a file from mongodb with golang

Tags: mongodb, go, gridfs, fileserver

I am working on a go project where I need to serve files stored in mongodb. The files are stored in a GridFs. I use gopkg.in/mgo.v2 as package to connect and query the db.

I can retrieve the file from the db, that is not hard.

```
f, err := s.files.OpenId(id)
```

But how can I serve that file with http?
I work with the JulienSchmidt router to handle all the other restfull requests.
The solutions I find always use static files, not files from a db.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why should it be any different? The GridFS implementations all make the output "look like a file". So it's just the same as reading any file handle and returning the content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tip: Recommended to use [`github.com/globalsign/mgo`](https://github.com/globalsign/mgo) instead of `gopkg.in/mgo.v2` (the latter is not maintained anymore).

---

The [`mgo.GridFile`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo#GridFS.Open) type implements [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader), so you could use [`io.Copy()`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy) to copy its content into the [`http.ResponseWriter`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter).

But since `mgo.GridFile` also implements [`io.Seeker`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Seeker), you may take advantage of [`http.ServeContent()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeContent). Quoting its doc:

> The main benefit of ServeContent over io.Copy is that it handles Range requests properly, sets the MIME type, and handles If-Match, If-Unmodified-Since, If-None-Match, If-Modified-Since, and If-Range requests.

Example handler serving a file:

```
func serveFromDB(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var gridfs *mgo.GridFS // Obtain GridFS via Database.GridFS(prefix)

    name := "somefile.pdf"
    f, err := gridfs.Open(name)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Failed to open %s: %v", name, err)
        http.Error(w, "something went wrong", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    defer f.Close()

    http.ServeContent(w, r, name, time.Now(), f) // Use proper last mod time
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about that but had hoped that there would be another solution with which I could serve the file directly...

Comment: @WimVanLaer Once you have the `GridFile` open, it's a single line: `http.ServeContent()`. What simpler do you wish for? Obviously how a source is opened is specific to the source. You may create a utility function to which you just pass the `w`, `r` and `name` params if you need to use this in multiple places.

Comment: oh I forgot that the GridFile implements the seeker file, misread that part... my bad

Answer (score 1):

its old but i got another solution with goMongo driver by importing
`"go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/gridfs"`

```
var bucket *gridfs.Bucket //creates a bucket
dbConnection, err := db.GetDBCollection() //connect db with your your
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
bucket, err = gridfs.NewBucket(dbConnection)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
name := "br100_update.txt"
downloadStream, err := bucket.OpenDownloadStreamByName(name)
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("Failed to open %s: %v", name, err)
    http.Error(w, "something went wrong", http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}
defer func() {
    if err := downloadStream.Close(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}()

// Use SetReadDeadline to force a timeout if the download does not succeed in 
// 2 seconds.
 if err = downloadStream.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(2 * time.Second)); err 
  != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
 }
```

// this code below use to read the file

```
 fileBuffer := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
 if _, err := io.Copy(fileBuffer, downloadStream); err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
```

}